# BigQuery compare all the columns(100+) from two rows in a sinle table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have input table as below-

| id | col1 | col2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | abc | 001 | 12:00 |
| 01 | def | 002 | 12:10 |

Required output table-

| id | col1 | col2 | time | diff_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | abc | 001 | 12:00 | null |
| 01 | def | 002 | 12:10 | col1,col2 |

I need to compare both the rows and find all the columns for which there is difference in value and keep those column names in a new column **diff_field**.

I need a optimized solution for this as my table has more than 100 columns(all the columns need to be compared)

Comment: make instructions more clear? are you comparing row against row and record which columns had different values in the latter row?  if so why does your output table diff_field column second row does not have "time" as values in time column are different in row1 vs row2?

Answer (score 1):

Below approach has no dependency on actual columns' names or any names convention rather then only `id` and `time`

```
create temp function extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
select t.*, 
  ( select string_agg(col)
    from unnest(extract_keys(cur)) as col with offset
    join unnest(extract_values(cur)) as cur_val with offset using(offset)
    join unnest(extract_values(prev)) as prev_val with offset using(offset)
    where cur_val != prev_val and col != 'time'
  ) as diff_field
from (
  select t, to_json_string(t) cur, to_json_string(ifnull(lag(t) over(win), t)) prev
  from your_table t
  window win as (partition by id order by time)
)
```

if apply to sample data in your question (or rather extended version of it that I borrowed from Jaytiger answer) - the output is

[image]

Comment: It works great for me with over 200+ columns; thank you! In combination with comparing tables in the attached answer, I was able to perform unit testing to check the consistency of my query and find the differences https://stackoverflow.com/a/57912743/7224607

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below approach:

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '01' id, 'abc' col1, '001' col2, '12:00' time UNION ALL
  SELECT '01' id, 'def' col1, '002' col2, '12:10' time UNION ALL
  SELECT '01' id, 'def' col1, '002' col2, '12:20' time UNION ALL
  SELECT '01' id, 'ddf' col1, '002' col2, '12:30' time
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(curr, prev),
       (SELECT STRING_AGG('col' || offset) 
          FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(curr)) c WITH offset
          JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(prev)) p WITH offset USING (offset)
         WHERE c <> p AND offset < ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(curr)) - 1
       ) diff_field
  FROM (
    SELECT *, FORMAT('%t', t) AS curr, LAG(FORMAT('%t', t)) OVER w AS prev
      FROM sample_table t
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time)
  );
```

**Query results**

[image]